# Is it correct to convert from computed property to lazy variable under constant struct?

Tags: swift

I wanted to change my code to use `lazy` variable instead of Computed property.
this code works

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
}
struct Size {
    var width = 10.0, height = 10.0
}
struct Rect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    var center: Point{
        get{
            let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
            let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
            return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        }
    }}
let shape = Rect()
print(shape.center)
```

But this code produces an error

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
}
struct Size {
    var width = 10.0, height = 10.0
}
struct Rect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    lazy var center = Point(x: origin.x + (size.width / 2), y: origin.y + (size.height / 2)) 
}
let shape = Rect()
print(shape.center)
```

I can fix the error if I changed `let shape = Rect()` to variable type `var shape = Rect()` OR when I change `Rect` to class instead of struct
What is wrong with my code and why does it give me error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that getting a lazy property potentially *changes* the struct value. Its state could change from "the lazy property has not been computed" to "the lazy property has been computed". This is why the getters of lazy properties are `mutating`.

A `let` constant does not allow its value to change, so you can't use `mutating` members on it. `var`s do, so that's why using a `var` makes your code compile.

Changing `Rect` to a class makes it a [reference type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html#ID89). This means that the `let` constant `shape` stores a reference to an instance of `Rect`, and this reference cannot be changed (e.g. you can't do `shape = someOtherRect` afterwards). However, the instance of `Rect` can still be changed (remember that the `let` constant is only storing a reference to it), and so getting a lazy property is fine on `shape`, when `Rect` is a class. Doing this will only potentially change the instance of `Rect`.

In my opinion, it is not appropriate to change `Rect.center` to a lazy property. After the first use of its getter, `center` will stay unchanged even if you change `origin` or `size`:

```
var shape = Rect()
print(shape.center)
shape.size = Size(width: 100, height: 100)
// now shape.center is incorrect!
```